# How do i return data from CupertinoTimerPicker inside showModalBottomSheet on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I return data from CupertinoTimerPicker(timerpicker.dart) back to showModalBottomSheet(form.dart) on flutter?

I wanted to use navigator.pop or sth but its doesnt sth like a ondismissed() function?

timerpicker.dart

```
class TimerModal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerModalState createState() => _TimerModalState();
}

class _TimerModalState extends State<TimerModal> {
  Duration _initialtimer = new Duration();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
            mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
            minuteInterval: 1,
            secondInterval: 1,
            initialTimerDuration: _initialtimer,
            onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration changedtimer) {
              setState(() {
                _initialtimer = changedtimer;
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      );
  }
}
```

form.dart

```
  FlatButton _timerPickerModal() {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.white,
      textColor: Colors.grey,
      disabledColor: Colors.grey,
      disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
      // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      // splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      onPressed: () async {
        final result = await showModalBottomSheet(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) => TimerModal()
        );
        print(result);
        // setState(() {
        //   _newTimer = result;
        // });
      },
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Timer: " + _checkTimerText(_newTimer),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a callback `onDateTimeChanged` to `CupertinoDatePicker`.

Every time a date is selected, the callback will be executed.

In this case you could add a callback to `TimerModal` and provide it to `CupertinoDatePicker`. Something like this:

```
FlatButton _timerPickerModal() {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.white,
      textColor: Colors.grey,
      disabledColor: Colors.grey,
      disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
      onPressed: () async {
        final result = await showModalBottomSheet(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) => TimerModal(
            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime date) {
              // In date variable you have the new date selected
              // Here you can do anything you need with it
              print(date);
            },
          ),
        );
        print(result);
        // setState(() {
        //   _newTimer = result;
        // });
      },
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Timer: " + _checkTimerText(_newTimer),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```